# MPMoviePlayerController seek forward in fullscreen mode until end is stuck

Tags: ipad, mpmovieplayercontroller, fullscreen

There seems to be a problem with the MPMoviePlayerController where once you're in fullscreen mode and you hold down the fast forward button, letting it seek forward (playing at fast speed) all the way to the end of the video.

Thereafter the you just get a black screen and it's stuck. In other words it does not respond to any taps gestures and you can not get out of this situation. Has anyone else encountered this problem?

Is there anyway to work around it in code?

Answer (score 1):

It seems it's an iOS bug since fast backward to the very beginning won't cause the black screen but fast forward to the end will, and after that the 'play'/'pause' call to the video player never works. I temporarily fix this by adding protected logic into the scrubber refresh callback:
let's assume that monitorPlaybackTime will be called in 'PLAY_BACK_TIME_MONITOR_INTERVAL' seconds period to refresh the scrubber, and in it I add a check logic:

```
NSTimeInterval duration = self.moviePlayer.duration;
NSTimeInterval current = self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackTime;

if (isnan(current) || current > duration) {
    current = duration;
} else if (self.moviePlayer.playbackState == MPMoviePlaybackStateSeekingForward) {
    if (current + self.moviePlayer.currentPlaybackRate*PLAY_BACK_TIME_MONITOR_INTERVAL > duration) {
        [self.moviePlayer endSeeking];
    }
}
```

A workaround to solve the black screen, not perfect, hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks @olinYY! What is the playableDuration doing in there? You declare it but then don't use it?

Comment: @Tony, this snippet is only part of the whole functional code, so playableDuration is used for other purposes, I forgot to remove it before paste, sorry to bother you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing you are not handling the [MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW24). You really should if you're not.

Still its unexpected for me that the movie player would go into a "stuck" state like you describe. I would more readily expect it to stop playback automatically and reset when it reaches the end. Anyway, I think your problem will go away if you observe the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification and handle the movie controller appropriately.

Comment: I've tried to handle this notification but I don't know what to do there to stop this problem.  I really think this is an Apple bug.  In other words, I just want the default controls to be there.  I think you can reproduce the problem even without going to full screen if you set your control style to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen.

Comment: @hey68you Hold on, you've lost me. You have to explain yourself again. Your movie is actually embedded (not fullscreen) and you are setting the controls to MPMovieControlStyleFullscreen?

Comment: here's the sequence. **step1:** create a movie player controller & add the player.view as a subview (setting its frame < full screen), start play `[player play];` (don't set any control style) **step2:** in runtime while the video is playing tap on the player to bring up the controls and tap on the fullscreen icon (or just pinch to zoom to fullscreen. **step3:** tap again to bring up the fullscreen controls which has a ff button. **step4:** hold down the ff button until end of playback. A full black screen is shown & no taps or pinches are handled; you can't get out without exiting the app ---

Answer (score 0):

Ran into the same issue on iOS6. Managed to fix it by registering for the MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification (as suggested by Leuguimerius) with the following implementation:

```
- (void)playbackDidFisnish:(NSNotification *)notif {
    if (self.player.currentPlaybackTime <= 0.1) {
    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        [self.player stop];
        [self.player play];
        [self.player pause];
        });
    }
}
```

Where self.player is the associated MPMoviePlayerController instance. The check against currentPlaybackTime serves to distinguish the more standard invocations of playbackDidFinish (where the movie is allowed to play at normal speed until its end) from those scenarios where the user fast forwards until the end. Stopping then playing and pausing results in a usable, visually consistent interface even when fast-forwarding to the end.

Answer (score 0):

None of the aforementioned solutions worked for me, so this is what I ended up doing:

```
NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self, selector: Selector("moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange"), name: MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification, object: nil)

func moviePlayerLoadStateDidChange() {
    let loadState = moviePlayerController?.loadState

    if loadState == MPMovieLoadState.Unknown {
        moviePlayerController?.contentURL = currentmovieURL
        moviePlayerController?.prepareToPlay()
    }
}
```

I think the issue is that when the seek foraward button is single pressed, it wants to skip to the next video, that's why a loading indicator appears. Listening for the load state change event, you can specify what the next video should be, and if you don't have any, you can just give it the same url.