# MPMoviePlayerController fast forward in full screen mode issue?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [MPMoviePlayerController seek forward in fullscreen mode until end is stuck](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982664/mpmovieplayercontroller-seek-forward-in-fullscreen-mode-until-end-is-stuck)

When I do fast forward in full screen mode in MPMoviePlayerController screen turns black and then I cant do any thing.

this is a major issue I am facing ,please help me.

Comment: add some relevant code right now this is not even guesswork

Comment: @Daij-Djan I have not done any special coding , check this question on stack http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6982664/mpmovieplayercontroller-seek-forward-in-fullscreen-mode-until-end-is-stuck. i has answer but I am not getting it.

Comment: handle the didFinish notifications as explained there.. ill try it as well

Answer (score 0):

the clue is to handle // Register to receive a notification when the movie has finished playing.

```
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self  
                                     selector:@selector(moviePlayBackDidFinish:)  
                                         name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                       object:moviePlayer]


- (void) moviePlayBackDidFinish:(NSNotification*)notification {  
  MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayer = [notification object];  
  [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self  
                                                  name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification  
                                                object:moviePlayer];  

    [moviePlayer dismissVC];  
  [moviePlayer release];  
  }
```